# Can I combine :last-child with * in css or sass?

Tags: css, sass

Here's my current code:

```
.loken5 *
   padding-right: 5px
.loken5:last-child
   padding: 0
```

Is there any way in SASS that I can use just 1 '.loken5' tag? (purpose is for saving space). Thank you :)

Comment: is the last style suppose to be `.loken5 *:last-child` ?

Answer (score 2):

Sass:

```
.loken5 
   &:last-child 
      padding: 0
   * 
      padding-right: 5px
```

Scss:

```
.loken5 {
   &:last-child {
      padding: 0;
   }
   * {
      padding-right: 5px;
   }
}
```

If you want `.loken5 *:last-child`:

```
.loken5 
   * 
      padding-right: 5px
      &:last-child 
          padding: 0
```

Checkout [this article](https://css-tricks.com/the-sass-ampersand/) if you want to know more about the `&` (SASS ampersant)

Comment: Thank you very much ! This will save a lot of space and view for my further codes. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help :)